# Sound not working anymore after first use of GPIO

Tags: gpio, audio, alsa

On a Raspberry Pi 3 with as of today latest firmware and raspbian, I have e.g. `espeak "hi"` or `aplay some.wav` working after booting into a small loudspeaker plugged into the jack (this is headless, no X11 desktop; no HDMI monitor connected).

Now as soon as I use GPIO (e.g. https://github.com/pololu/dual-mc33926-motor-driver-rpi/blob/master/example.py to run a Motor), even after that's finished and released anything it has to release (or does it?), then sound won't work anymore (until I reboot); e.g. aplay fails with:

```
aplay: pcm_write:1939: write error: Input/output error
```

How are playing sound and GPIO related on the RPi, and what do you have to do you use both together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely clash is with GPIO 18/19/20/21 (pins 12/35/38/40).

PWM (medium quality audio) uses GPIO 18/19, PCM (high quality audio) uses GPIO 18/19/20/21.

Check to see what your motor driver is using which clashes and use alternative GPIO.

Comment: Aha. Yep, motor indeed uses e.g. RaspiBcmPin GPIO_12 (in Pi4j  "BROADCOM_PIN_NUMBERING"), see [1] Motors driver class source. Using alternative GPIO on that [2] Motor shield appears to require to cut traces on the board and re-soldering... :-( There is no (easier) way to make PWM or PCM use another GPIO instead, is there?

[1] https://github.com/vorburger/dual-mc33926-motor-driver-pi4j/blob/d03debadab7b8a1b87f63e362a7e733c4968431a/src/main/java/ch/vorburger/raspberry/mc33926/Motors.java

[2] https://www.pololu.com/product/2755

Comment: @vorburger I don't think you can alter the GPIO used for audio.  But I do not use audio at all on the Pi so I may be wrong.